# getStatus response with behat and selenium2

Tags: selenium, behat, acceptance-testing, mink

I have test in behat for getting a status response, but I have this error:

[image]

This is my scenario:

```
Feature: Google

      @javascript

      Scenario: Search
        Given I am on the homepage
        When I go to "http://stackoverflow.com"
        Then I wait 3 seconds
        And the response status code should be 200
```

Code ph:

```
 /**
 * @Then the response status code should be :arg1
 */
public function theResponseStatusCodeShouldBe($arg1)
{
    if ((string)$this->_response->getStatusCode() !== $arg1) {
 var_dump('HTTP code does not match '.$httpStatus.' (actual: '.$this->_response->getStatusCode().')');
    }

}
```

How to I resolve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid redefining existing steps.
You already have this step in MinkContext.

You should use an IDE editor that has autocomplete in feature files like phpstorm.

`Ambiguous match` errors are because methods with the same snippet are already defined.
You cannot define steps using the same snippet.